# Optimizing code VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I dont know if anyone will be able to understand this code..because I know it is very sloppy :/. I am new to VBA, so I am aware of only limited functions. This is a linear interpolator tool I created. It interpolates for some approx 9000 rows and prints data in different columns(with each column corresponding to a table present in separate sheets.) I want to know if there is a way to optimize this code..so that it can run faster ?

```
Option Explicit
Dim x(1 To 9000) As Double, y(1 To 9000) As Double, z1(1 To 9000) As Double, z2(1 To 9000) As Double, V(1 To 9000) As Double, x1 As Double, y1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double, I1(1 To 9000) As Double, I2(1 To 9000) As Double, R1(1 To 9000) As Double, R2(1 To 9000) As Double, a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, Result(1 To 9000) As Double

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer, r As Integer, s As Integer, t As Integer, hp As Integer
Dim ws As Sheets

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Double Energy -FF", "EF8", "EF10", "EF12", "EF14", "EF16", "EF18"))

For hp = 2 To 7
For k = 1 To 9000

 With ws(1)
  V(k) = .Cells(k + 2, 6).Value
 End With


 With ws(hp)

 If (V(k) <= 0.5) And (V(k) <> 0) Then
  x(k) = 0.5
  x1 = .Cells(2, 1).Value
  z1(k) = .Cells(k + 2, 1).Value
 End If


For i = 1 To 6

    If (.Cells(2, i).Value <= V(k)) And (V(k) <= .Cells(2, i + 1).Value) And Not (IsEmpty(V(k))) Then
    p = i
    x1 = .Cells(2, p).Value
    x2 = .Cells(2, p + 1).Value
    x(k) = V(k)
    z1(k) = .Cells(k + 2, p).Value
    z2(k) = .Cells(k + 2, p + 1).Value

    End If
    Next i


 If V(k) = Empty Then

  Result(k) = 0

 Else

 R1(k) = (z2(k) - z1(k)) / (x2 - x1)
 R2(k) = (x(k) - x1) * R1(k)
 Result(k) = R2(k) + z1(k)

 End If
 End With

 With ws(1)
  .Cells(k + 2, hp + 6).Value = Result(k)
 End With

 Next k
 Next hp
End Sub
```

Comment: This sort of question isn't really within the scope of Stack Overflow, you'd be better off moving this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Just be sure to check their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to check your question is on-topic there.

Comment: you could *load* everything into arrays instead of working with cells directly. You could turn off application.screenupdating = false/true start and end of macro.

Comment: The less you use the spreadsheet access, the faster it'll run. Load the input range into a variant array in a single operation. And then work on it. And you need to read up on optimizing VBA in general.

Comment: @Aiken As I said I am new..so i was unaware..will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

**V(k)** does not depend on **h.**  Therefore you can remove it from the loop over **h.**

Look for other opportunities to remove calculations from the **h** loop.